# Reverse event Listener

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and I have made a javascript code that takes your password and then see if it matches with the Confirm password, then it will tell you whether they match or not, this works fine when I put the password first then the confirm password, but when I do it the other way around it says it's invalid. Basically, I don't how to make it if a user first puts in their confirm password then their password so it shows up as valid.

```js
const password = document.getElementById("password");
const Cpassword = document.getElementById("Cpassword")

password.addEventListener('input', () => {
const passBox = document.querySelector('.passBox');
const passText = document.querySelector('.passText');
const passPattern = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
if (password.value.match(passPattern)) {
passBox.classList.add('valid');
passBox.classList.remove('invalid');
passText.innerHTML = "Your password in Valid";
        } else {
            passBox.classList.add('invalid');
            passBox.classList.remove('valid');
            passText.innerHTML = "Your password must be at least 6 characters as well as contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase, and one number.";
            
        }

    });


Cpassword.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

    var CpassBox = document.querySelector('.CpassBox');
    var CpassText = document.querySelector('.CpassText');

    if (document.getElementById('password').value == document.getElementById('Cpassword').value) {
        CpassBox.classList.add('valid');
        CpassBox.classList.remove('invalid');
        CpassText.innerHTML = "Password match";
    } else {
        CpassBox.classList.add('invalid');
        CpassBox.classList.remove('valid');
        CpassText.innerHTML = "Password does not match";
        
    }

});
```

```html
<input type='password' id='password'>
<p class='passBox'></p>
<p class='passText'></p>
<input type='password' id='Cpassword'>
<p class='CpassBox'></p>
<p class='CpassText'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the code a bit.

What i done:

- Fix variable with const and put outside.
- Create a function `CheckCPassword()` and use it into password input so that will check if match after input letter.
- in `CheckCPassword()` add an if for check if password have or not value.

```js
const password = document.getElementById("password");
const Cpassword = document.getElementById("Cpassword")
const CpassBox = document.querySelector('.CpassBox');
const CpassText = document.querySelector('.CpassText');
const passBox = document.querySelector('.passBox');
const passText = document.querySelector('.passText');
const passPattern = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;

password.addEventListener('input', () => {

  if (password.value.match(passPattern)) {
    passBox.classList.add('valid');
    passBox.classList.remove('invalid');
    passText.innerHTML = "Your password in Valid";
  } else {
    passBox.classList.add('invalid');
    passBox.classList.remove('valid');
    passText.innerHTML = "Your password must be at least 6 characters as well as contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase, and one number.";

  }
  CheckCPassword();

});


Cpassword.addEventListener('input', () => {
  CheckCPassword();
});

function CheckCPassword() {
  if (password.value === '' || Cpassword.value === '') {
    return;
  }
  if (password.value === Cpassword.value) {
    CpassBox.classList.add('valid');
    CpassBox.classList.remove('invalid');
    CpassText.innerHTML = "Password match";
  } else {
    CpassBox.classList.add('invalid');
    CpassBox.classList.remove('valid');
    CpassText.innerHTML = "Password does not match";

  }
}
```

```html
<input type='password' id='password'>
<p class='passBox'></p>
<p class='passText'></p>
<input type='password' id='Cpassword'>
<p class='CpassBox'></p>
<p class='CpassText'></p>
```